# how can I create a content slide without using the TSFE context

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I use the `content_from_pid` field to receive the page-content from a global sys-folder instead of the page itself. This works great but I would like to add a header image from the original page context and the header image should be inherited from the parent pages if it isn`t present in the page itself.

An alternative would be to use "insert records" content elements. But the drawback is, that new content in the global sys-folder would not be referenced. You would have to link those new contents in every "insert records" element that references the sys-folder with the new content.

So I need a way to define exceptions to the general content replacement triggered by `content_from_pid`.

Technically `content_from_pid` triggers `clone $tsfe;` in the core "/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageGenerator.php".

So I guess I have to either overwrite this core function or modify the TS which is just `styles.content.get` with a different colPos and slide = -1 atm.

Example page tree:

```
- [1] global content
-- [2] content source for product Y
-- [7] content source for contact pages

- [3] home page with header image Z
-- [4] product Y page with content-from-pid 2 and headerimg Z from 3
-- [5] page with normal content and header image from 3
-- [6] another page with content-from-pid 7 and headerimg Z from 3

- [8] home page with header image X
-- [9] product Y page with content-from-pid 2 and headerimg X from 8
-- [10] page with normal content and header image from 8
-- [11] another page with content-from-pid 7 and headerimg X from 8
```

Comment: Could you publish the relevant parts of the page tree? Is it only one page where you use the `content-from-pid` mechanism?

Comment: Thanks, I use content-from-pid on a lot of pages. I added a simplified page-tree to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because the rendering for your current page never starts, because it is redirected to the `content_from_pid` page.

Instead of using `content_from_pid` page, you should create yourself a small content element (or abuse some other content element) and adjust the rendering. You can use the `CONTENT` object to render the content from the other `pid` as long as you can somehow get this `pid`.

Comment: Thanks, I`ll try to go this way. I could add a custom field to the pages table to store the ID of the content-source sys folder.

Comment: you also could use the shortcut CE with only one reference to the source page (so you may loose the colPos information) instead of refrencing each CE from the source page.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ but the shortcut CEs element browser is limited to content elements - so I can`t reference the source page itself?

Comment: I have to admitt: I have seen this feature and thought it was build in in TYPO3, but it seems it was an added feature (it is possible to enhance the shortcut CE with any kind of records). So it would be easy to implement that feature to include only records in the same language, colPos, ....